# extract Similar users from logs using hadoop/pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

We need as part of our start-up product to compute "similar user feature". And we've decided to go with pig for it.
I've been learning pig for a few days now and understand how it work.
So to start here is how the log file look like.

```
user        url             time
user1       http://someurl.com      1235416
user1       http://anotherlik.com       1255330
user2       http://someurl.com      1705012
user3       http://something.com        1705042
user3       http://someurl.com      1705042
```

As the number of users and url can be huge, we can't use a bruteforce approach here, so first we need to find the user's that have access at least to on common url.

The algorithm could be splited as bellow:

1. Find all users that has accessed to some common urls.
2. generate pair-wise combination of all users for each resource accessed.
3. for each pair and and url, compute the similarity of those users: the similarity depend of the timeinterval between the access (so we need to keep track of the time).
4. sum up for each pair-url the similarity.

here is what i've written so far:

```
A = LOAD 'logs.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (uid:bytearray, url:bytearray, time:long);
grouped_pos = GROUP A BY ($1);
```

I know it is not much yet, but now i don't know how to generate the pair or move further.
So any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice, detailed [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.163.1677) from IBM on doing co-clustering with MapReduce that may be useful for you.

The Google News Personalization [paper](http://iws.seu.edu.cn/resource/Proceedings/WWW/2007/papers/paper570.pdf) describes a fairly straightforward implementation of Locality Sensitive Hashing for solving the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For algorithms, look at papers on query/URL bipartite graphs.  Here are a couple of links:

Query suggestion using hitting time
by Qiaozhu Mei, Dengyong Zhou, Kenneth Church
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~qmei/pub/cikm08-sugg.ppt

Random walks on the click graph
Nick Craswell and Martin Szummer
July 2007
http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=65235

Comment: Thanks for those great docs. It was very useful and i learnt alot. However i'm not able to see how i can use those algorithms to match users. My goal is not to suggest links, but to suggest to each user in the system a set of users he has the most similarities just based on the number of pages they have both seens. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In your above example, you can create a bipartite graph where user1-someurl-user2 and user1-someurl-user3.  The edge weight user1 to someurl is 0.5 (though you could also incorporate time here to adjust the weight if you wanted) and 0.5 from user1 to someotherlink. user2 to someurl is 1.0 (only visited one page). And user3 to someurl is 0.5 (user3 visited 2 pages).  Adding the edge weights you get a similarity of 1.5 (out of 2) for user1 -> user2 and 1.0 for user1 -> user3. This is the basic idea I was suggesting with the above papers.